# Guard Case Assignment

Tags: swift

Well...here is the code

```
func howMany() -> Int {
   return 10
}

func Call() -> Void {
   guard case let output = howMany(), output > 5 else { return }
}

Call()
```

I do not really understand how the guard case works. This looks pretty much like a pattern matching condition where we compare whether the result of **howMany()** is equal to **output**, if it is, assign the value to **output** and then compare it to the literal value **5**. However, when I deleted the line of **output > 5**, the compiler said, **"the guard condition is always true, body is unreachable."**

According to the pattern, if we translate it into a switch statement, it looks pretty much like this

```
switch howMany() {
   case let output where output > 5:
      break;
}
```

The question is if it could be directly translated into the switch statement, then there should not be a warning of **"the guard condition is always true, body is unreachable"** when we delete the where condition.

I hope somebody could shed some light on this.

Comment: The use of case in a guard condition allows you to use non optional value assignment. Btw The warning is true considering that you are returning a constant from your method. If you don't need the condition just use `let output = howMany()`. Note that it is Swift naming convention to name your methods starting with a lowercase letter

Comment: what condition are you referring to? I do not see the condition except the where clause works as a condition. I still do not get it.

Comment: A comma (`,`) in a conditional statement basically means `and // &&` - but they are evaluated one-at-a-time. This allows you to create the variable `output`, and then compare it with `5` - otherwise, the compiler will say `"output"` does not exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider:

```
func foo() {
    guard case let output = howMany(), output > 5 else {
        print("less than or equal to 5")
        return
    }

    print("\(output) is greater than 5")
}
```

That is roughly equivalent to:

```
func bar() {
    switch howMany() {
    case let output where output > 5:
        print("\(output) is greater than 5")

    default:
        print("less than or equal to 5")
        return
    }
}
```

If you remove that `> 5` criteria:

```
func foo() {
    guard case let output = howMany() else {
        print("less than or equal to 5")
        return
    }

    print("\(output) is greater than 5")
}
```

You get your warning:

> 'guard' condition is always true, body is unreachable

That warning is correct, because the body *is* unreachable.

And if you do the equivalent in the `switch` example:

```
func bar() {
    switch howMany() {
    case let output:
        print("\(output) is greater than 5")

    default:
        print("less than or equal to 5")
        return
    }
}
```

If you do that, you will receive an analogous warning:

> default will never be executed

And, again, it makes sense, because `default` will not be reached.

Now, consider your example `switch` with no `default` clause:

```
func bar() {
    switch howMany() {
    case let output:
        print("output:", output)
    }
}
```

You don't receive a warning here only because there is no `default` clause (the analog of the "body" of the `guard` statement).